# Creating alpine package adding extra files

Tags: alpine-linux

I am trying to create my first alpine package that does the fallowing

- install docker (done)
- install diaglog (done)
- copy an script (comes with the package) and places in an folder in /opts/
- create an user
- set script to run when created user logs on to system

my problem is i am not sure how to include the script, or during install move it to the correct location.

Comment: hay thanks to the alpine IRC i worked it out i needed to add

install -Dm644 COPYING "$pkgdir"/usr/share/licenses/$pkgname/COPYING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hay thanks to the alpine IRC i worked it out i needed to add

`install -Dm644 COPYING "$pkgdir"/usr/share/licenses/$pkgname/COPYING`